# Xpath Expression to get count of elements conditionally

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the below XML sample

```
<TravelerIDs AssociationID="1">
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
        <CustomParams>
            <Param Name="AGE">
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">4</Value>
            </Param>
            <Param Name="IsKnownTraveler">
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</Value>
            </Param>
        </CustomParams>
    </TravelerIDs>
    <TravelerIDs AssociationID="2">
        <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
        <CustomParams>
            <Param Name="AGE">
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">8</Value>
            </Param>
        </CustomParams>
    </TravelerIDs>
    <TravelerIDs AssociationID="3">
        <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
        <CustomParams>
            <Param Name="AGE">
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">8</Value>
            </Param>
        </CustomParams>
    </TravelerIDs>
```

i am trying to get the count of TravelerIDs which has Param element with name= AGE and Value greater than 5 and less than 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
//TravelerIDs[CustomParams//Param[@Name='AGE' and Value >= 8 and Value <= 14]]
```

And if you want the count:

```
count(//TravelerIDs[CustomParams//Param[@Name='AGE' and Value >= 8 and Value <= 14]])
```

Comment: I like the factoring of `CustomParams/Param[@Name="AGE"]`.   Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you know your document schema isn't going to change, is better not to use descendant axis because of possible performance cost. Use instead

```
count(
   /TravelerIDs
      /CustomParams
         /Param[@Name="AGE"]
            /Value[. > 5][. < 14]
)
```

Comment: Your performance advice is misguided.  First of all, XPath performance is nearly never an issue in practice; there's no reason to roll out the tired trope about `//` performance for simple XPath Q/As.   Secondly, we don't know what's above his `TravelerIDs` elements, but we know something's above it (or the XML isn't well-formed), so `//` is a convenient shorthand for disregarding unimportant heritage.

Comment: @kjhughes That's your opinion. But this `//*` selects every element in the document and this `/*` selects the document element. Thus, `descendant-or-self` axe is doing more work than `child` axe. Also `*` selects every node of the principal node type and `TravelerIDs` only selects `TravelerIDs` elements. Thus `*` node test is doing even more work than `TravelerIDs` node test. Whether this has "practical" impact as you said on the performance is a matter of benchmarking.

Comment: Having said that, perhaps I'm being critical beyond need here.   Touch your answer, and I'll undo the downvote and delete my comment trail; it's harsher than your answer deserves.

Comment: @kjhughes Don't worry, I upvoted this very good answer. Maybe you don't know Alejandro but everyone will soon get it that he is one of the best XSLT specialists that SO has seen -- I firmly believe in this. As for the `//` abbreviation and performance, he is generally right, Specific XPath engines may optimize for this, but in general we may not and should not expect this as a given. Welcome back Alejandro! BTW, Alejandro's XPath expression is not only potentially more efficient but is also twice as compact as yours -- hinting at more efficiencies possible in its evaluation

Comment: @Alejandro, I know that this is an XPath question, but maybe it would be good to remind people who would use this expression in XSLT (or in any other XML document) that the rules for XML well-formedness require '<' to be escaped.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: My XPath was indeed rough, and I'd already deleted it in favor of Ayoub_B's.  To this answer focusing on `//` performance, my hasty reaction was, "Sigh, we don't people parroting `//` performance concerns on incidental  `//` use."   But then his comment gave me pause, and yours confirmed my growing realization that he's not just parroting concerns.    Sorry, Alejandro.  I would still like the chance to withdraw my downvote.  And thanks, Dimitre, for confirming what I was (too slowly) coming to realize myself.

Comment: @kjhughes, No problem man, I just happen to know Alejandro a little bit -- to know and understand him one can look at all (maybe 2000) questions he answered as @ user357812 (https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20user357812) before he decided to leave SO a few years ago. I personally always read his answers with interest and in most cases learn a lot from them

Comment: Hi @DimitreNovatchev! I really appreciate your words. I came back because I'm having a bit of time to spare between proyects.